# Error while retrieving data from database to JTable which has JCheckbox in JTable using TableModelListener

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

My JTable has a column having JCheckBox for maintaining status. When I don't implement TableModelListener and run the program, the data gets displayed in JTable. But when I run the code with TableModelListener implemented I get error. java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

```
    package com.tag.pointOfsale;

    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Locale;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
    import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
    import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

    public class Return_Goods extends javax.swing.JDialog {

        PointSaleDao posDao = new PointSaleDao();

        public Return_Goods(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
            super(parent, modal);
            initComponents();


        jTable1.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
                @Override
                public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                    int row = e.getFirstRow();
                    int column = e.getColumn();

                    String sno = jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
            String code = jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString();
            String pro_name = jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString();
            String batch = jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString();
            String exp_date = jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 4).toString();
            String qty = jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 5).toString();
            String price = jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 6).toString();
            String total = jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 7).toString();
            String r_pro = jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 8).toString();

            if (column == 9) {
                TableModel model = (TableModel) e.getSource();
                String columnName = model.getColumnName(column);
                Boolean checked = (Boolean) model.getValueAt(row, column);
                if (checked) {
                    System.out.println(sno + "\t" + code + "\t" + pro_name + "\t" + true);
                } else {
                    System.out.println(sno + "\t" + code + "\t" + pro_name + "\t" + false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {

            jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            txtInvoice = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            txtPurchaseDate = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            txtPayment = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            txtSalesman = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            txtCustomer = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
            jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
            jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
            btnReturn = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            txtReturn = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
            txtDescription = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setTitle("Return Goods");

            jLabel1.setText("Invoice No.");

            txtInvoice.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
                public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
                    txtInvoiceFocusLost(evt);
                }
            });

            jLabel2.setText("Purchase Date : ");

            jLabel3.setText("Payment Method : ");

            jLabel4.setText("Salesman : ");

            jLabel5.setText("Customer Name : ");

            jTable1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
            jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                new Object [][] {

                },
                new String [] {
                    "S no.", "Code", "Name", "Batch No.", "Expiry Date", "Quantity", "Price", "Total Cost", "Return Qty", "Status"
                }
            ) {
                Class[] types = new Class [] {
                    java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Boolean.class
                };
                boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                    false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false
                };

                public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                    return types [columnIndex];
                }

                public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                    return canEdit [columnIndex];
                }
            });
            jTable1.setRowHeight(22);
            jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
            if (jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
                jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(15);
                jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(30);
                jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(30);
                jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(40);
                jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setPreferredWidth(40);
                jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(9).setPreferredWidth(15);
            }

            javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
            jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
            jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
            );
            jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 289, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            );

            btnReturn.setText("Return");
            btnReturn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    btnReturnActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jLabel6.setText("Returned On : ");

            jLabel7.setText("Description : ");

            txtDescription.setColumns(20);
            txtDescription.setRows(3);
            jScrollPane2.setViewportView(txtDescription);

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(btnReturn))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                .addComponent(jLabel7))
                            .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                        .addComponent(txtInvoice)
                                        .addComponent(txtPurchaseDate, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 126, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                            .addComponent(txtPayment, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 125, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                                            .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 103, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                            .addComponent(txtSalesman, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 126, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                            .addComponent(txtCustomer, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 126, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                            .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                            .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                                            .addComponent(txtReturn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 126, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 244, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))))
                    .addContainerGap())
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(txtInvoice, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addComponent(txtCustomer, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel6)
                            .addComponent(txtReturn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(txtPurchaseDate, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addComponent(txtPayment, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addComponent(txtSalesman, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel7)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 65, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 11, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(btnReturn)
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>                        

        private void txtInvoiceFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                     
            String invoice = txtInvoice.getText();

            posDao.returnProduct(invoice);
        }  

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
            //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
            /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
             * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
             */
            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;

                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Return_Goods.class
                        .getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Return_Goods.class
                        .getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Return_Goods.class
                        .getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Return_Goods.class
                        .getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            //</editor-fold>

            /* Create and display the dialog */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Return_Goods dialog = new Return_Goods(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
                    dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton btnReturn;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
        public static javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
        public static javax.swing.JTextField txtCustomer;
        private javax.swing.JTextArea txtDescription;
        private javax.swing.JTextField txtInvoice;
        public static javax.swing.JTextField txtPayment;
        public static javax.swing.JTextField txtPurchaseDate;
        private javax.swing.JTextField txtReturn;
        public static javax.swing.JTextField txtSalesman;
        // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

After adding TableModelListener, I am getting exception.java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 0):

```
int row = e.getFirstRow();
int column = e.getColumn();
```

I would guess one of the above variables contains -1.

Read your stack trace. It will tell you the line causing the problem.

A value of -1 means a row/column is not selected.

Then you need to modify the code in the listener to exit if either of the above values is -1.

Comment: Initially my JTable is empty. After searching particular Id, then only my JTable gets filled up.

Comment: @JikeshPrajapati, doesn't change my answer. You need to debug the problem yourself. We don't have access to your code or data.

Comment: column variable is generating value as -1 whereas row generates 0 as output. So, now how do I fix it.

Comment: Also, why does you code reference the `getSelectedRow()` method. A TableModelListener is only used for changes to the data, not changes in row selection. I have no idea why you have those 8 statements.

Comment: what actually i wanted to do is, when the checkbox is selected, then the value of the selected row to be displayed in JTextField. That's all I wanted to do.

Comment: @JikeshPrajapati, so then do that. You already have the row/column variables. So in the "if statement" you get the data you want to display. Using those variables. Don't get the data unless the if condition is true!